# get_bloginfo prints IP instead of url

Tags: redirect, htaccess, configuration, bloginfo, ip

I just recently moved a site to another production environment and I seem to have missed some setting in the db config as a lot of the built-in functions prints the IP instead of the url. Ideas?
Tried switching site_url and home under wp_options table from IP to http://project.dev (which is set to default to a specific IP where I manage my different local projects, running on Apache).

Entering http://project.dev/wp-admin gives me

```
http://192.168.33.21/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fproject.dev%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

Htaccess is set to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Database Search and Replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) and replace the IP `192.168.33.21` with the domain name `project.dev`.

Comment: Ah, you're right! WP stores the IP in the urls for each file path. Thanks for pointing that out.